# Grab POST data from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get Google sign-in to work on my site.
 
Everything works when i set the token id manually but I have no clue how to get it from an XMLHttpRequest.

**glogin.js**

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
      var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
      var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
      console.log('ID: ' + id_token); 
      console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
      console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
      console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'https://example.com/signup.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send('idtoken='+id_token);

    }
```

signup.php

```
<?php 
require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (!empty($_POST["idtoken"]) && $_POST["idtoken"] != NULL) {
        $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
        $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($_POST["idtoken"]);
    if ($payload) {
        $userid = $payload['sub'];
        echo 'valid';
    } else {
        // Invalid ID token
        echo 'invalid';
    }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
  console.log('ID: ' + id_token); 
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.

window.location.href = "https://example.com/signup.php?tokenid="+id_token;

}
```

I give up, why even waste my time with XMLHttpRequest when i can do this instead.